# How to get client certificate inside web method at asp.net web forms c#?

Tags: static, request, client, certificate, webmethod

I configure IIS to get certificates from client. And I can easily get client certificate inside event handler, for example Page_Load

```
HttpClientCertificate cert = Request.ClientCertificate;
```

Now I need to create web method what will get client name from certificate and return data for this client. But how can I get client certificate inside static web method where I don't have access to Request?

Comment: You _may_ have access to `HttpContext.Current.Request`.

Comment: **Thanks! :)** It's what I want. And I was looking from complex solution but everything is simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any method, including in a static method, you can use `HttpContext.Current`. If this is non-null, then you can access the `Request` property. If *that* is non-null, then you can access the `ClientCertificate` property.

Of course, it may be null...

Comment: It may be null? VS 2012 underlines condition ClientCertificate != null as "expression is always true".

Comment: VS2012 plus ReSharper, maybe?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have just looked at source of HttpRequest class. It's cannot be null.
`public HttpClientCertificate ClientCertificate { 
    [AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Level=AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Low)]
    get { 
        if (_clientCertificate == null) { 
            _clientCertificate = CreateHttpClientCertificateWithAssert();
        } 

        return _clientCertificate;
    }
}`

Comment: ReSharper uses information gleaned from the analysis of the code. Often, a derived class is determined to never return null, even though the base (or abstract) class might return null.